# Kivy audio seek don't work correctly

Tags: python, audio, kivy

When i try to use seek function of [kivy.core.audio](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html) module, i get this error:

```
File "./controller.kv", line 32, in < module >
on_press: root.action_play()
File "main.py", line 37, in action_play
self.sound.seek('30')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/audio/audio_gstplayer.py", line 79, in seek
self.player.seek(position / self.duration)
AttributeError: 'SoundGstplayer' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

This is my def code:

```
def action_play(self):
    self.label_wid.text = 'Sound played: ' + self.sound.source
    self.sound.seek('30')
    self.sound.play()
```

I tried to edit the file **core/audio/audio_gstplayer.py** in this way:

```
def seek(self, position):
    self.player.seek(position / self.duration)
```

by:

```
def seek(self, position):
    self.player.seek(position / self.get_length)
```

But not work....
If you have a solution to properly operate the seek function, I'm interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this has been fixed in development. You can wait for the next version (1.8.1) to be released, or you can [install the development version](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html#development-version) from GitHub.

Also, `self.sound.seek('30')` should be `self.sound.seek(30)`, as `seek` is expecting an `int`, not a `str`.

Comment: Very interesting information! So I try this: `self.sound.seek(30)` and i get this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'instancemethod'` ... I find more information here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1875

Comment: That's due to your change in the gstplayer code (`self.player.seek(position / self.get_length)`). `self.get_length` is an `instancemethod`. You want `self.length` instead, but there are also some other necessary changes. You should install the development version to fix this.

Comment: `self.get_length` return `0` error: `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` I tried to use: `self.player.get_duration()` ( [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/audio/audio_gstplayer.py#L87) ) but it return strange string: `-9.99999971718e-10` when it should look like this (for mp3 of 5 minutes): `300`  -_- I'll try the development version